# is there an easier way to load mysql driver to class path?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, driver, classpath

Im trying command line classpath approach but the docker run keeps giving class not found error ? is there an easier way to load mysql driver to class path?

The error:

```
Error:Error: Could not find or load main class com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk

COPY src src

WORKDIR src

RUN mkdir -p target

COPY target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar /target/

RUN javac ./com/smartworks/client/*.java

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp", "mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:target/*","com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there are problems in your Dockerfile, Please take a look below Dockerfile and change it according to that.

```
FROM openjdk

WORKDIR src # Good to define WORKDIR before any operation

COPY src . # As you are only copying src and change dest to Current directory which is src by default as WORKDIR is mentioned above

RUN mkdir -p target

RUN ls -lart #Add a debug to see if everyfile is present
COPY target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar target/ # Instead of /target , you have to copy to target

RUN javac ./com/smartworks/client/*.java 

#For Classpath
ENV CLASSPATH=libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:${CLASSPATH}

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "RDSConnectionTest"]
```

Comment: Hi Nischay, still same issue.  output provided below.                                                      $ docker run -t rdstest
Error: Could not find or load main class com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.smartworks.client.RDSConnectionTest

Comment: Can you add the output of `docker build` and `docker run`? Exact commands as well which you are running.

Comment: issue is resolved. i had to append the driver in classpath via command ENV CLASSPATH .

Comment: That's great. Can you post the Dockerfile change which you did, so that we everybody is aware about the answer

Comment: very generic version. should work for simple rds connection test from docker.                             ```FROM openjdk:8
COPY src . 
COPY target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar libs/
ENV CLASSPATH=libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:${CLASSPATH}
RUN javac /*.java
RUN ls -lart 
ENTRYPOINT ["java","RDSConnectionTest"]

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM openjdk
COPY src . 
COPY target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar libs/
ENV CLASSPATH=libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:${CLASSPATH}
RUN javac /*.java
ENTRYPOINT ["java","RDSConnectionTest"]
```